# Automapper limitations in terms of performance

Tags: c#, automapper

We are doing some load testing on our application and trying to stretch the limits a little.

We are using Automapper to convert from Entities to Dto, some properties might differ between the two, the mapping is the default one, by naming convention, no other transformation code is executed as part of the mapping.

On objects with about 5 properties it takes about 1 minute to transform 16000 objects. 
Specifying the mapping with ForMember for each of the matching properties didn't provide any improvement.

This is happening on a machine: i7 Quad Core CPU @ 2.4GHz, 64bit Windows 7 with about 10Gb of Ram available.

The application is a web application running under IISExpress.

Is this consistent with your experience of Automapper ?

Comment: I do regular benchmarks of AutoMapper (found in the Benchmark project in the codebase). I get about 2 seconds to map 100K objects. What does your usage look like? Config, source/dest types and how you run it would show me if you're doing something different.